# Scrapy: How to insert data into SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy

I'm trying to write a dictionary into sql database, but without success giving me:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO posts(url, First_and_Last_Name) VALUES("%s", "%s")' % (url, First_and_Last_Name))
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
```

spider:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy
import sqlite3

class Wellness(scrapy.Spider):
name = "wellness"
start_urls = ['https://www.wellness.com/dir/6022571/acupuncturist/ri/east-greenwich/hwasook-lee-phoenix-fertility-center-dac']

def parse(self, response):
    item = {
            'url' : response.request.url,
            'First_and_Last_Name' : response.css('h1::text').get(),
    }       
    directions_link = response.css('#directions_tab a::attr(href)').get()
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(directions_link), callback=self.parse_directions, meta={'item': item})

def parse_directions(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['Phone'] = response.css('.tel::text').get()
    yield item

    db = sqlite3.connect('posts.db')
    db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,url TEXT, First_and_Last_Name TEXT);''') 
    db.commit()

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO posts(url, First_and_Last_Name) VALUES("%s", "%s")' % (url, First_and_Last_Name))

    db.commit()
    db.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(Wellness)
    process.start()
```

What am I doing wrong here. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your using ``url`` but where have u defined it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `item['url']` instead of `url`, same for `First_and_Last_Name`:

```py
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO posts(url, First_and_Last_Name) VALUES("%s", "%s")' % (item['url'], item['First_and_Last_Name']))
```

Also, don't use string formatting with SQL statements, as it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Let the [`cursor.execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) method do the escaping for you:

```py
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO posts(url, First_and_Last_Name) VALUES(?, ?)', (item['url'], item['First_and_Last_Name']))
```